# Why can we perceive oscillating electromagnetic waves but not static fields?

Tags: electromagnetism

If we have a physical wave, say a waves in ocean, then we can observe still ocean and also disturbed waves on it with sight. But, why can't we do observe still eletromagnetic field with sight?

Comment: I do not think the video you are referring to is fundamental to understanding your question. If I am wrong, you should explain explicitly the connection between the video and your question (besides visualizing time-varying patterns of fields)

Comment: With your. edit you have changed quite a lot your question. I'll see if I can adapt my answer.

Comment: I can perceive static electric fields via the hairs in my arms

Answer (score 1):

Observing oceanic waves (through visible light) and perceiving electromagnetic fields outside the visible range are two different capabilities of our eyes. The former just exploits our eyes' ability to perceive a range of frequencies in the electromagnetic spectrum.

About the latter, it is not true that we can perceive by sight electromagnetic waves of any frequency. Evolution allowed our eyes to see only a restricted range of frequencies, the so-called [visible range](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visible_spectrum), spanning from about $400$ to $790$ THz. Infrared and ultraviolet radiations are already invisible to our eyes, although it is not the same for other animals. For example, pigeons can see light in the near UV range. Our eyes' blindness to frequencies outside the visible range extends to very low and zero frequencies.

However, it is not totally accurate that we cannot probe static electric fields with our bodies. If the fields are intense enough, we can. We feel the effect of a static polarizing electric field on our hair (see, for instance, this [Wikipedia image](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electric_field#/media/File:Van_de_Graaff_Generator_-_Science_City_-_Calcutta_1997_444.JPG) ).

---

**Addendum after the edit of the question**

Observing oceanic waves and electromagnetic (em) waves with sight are different things.

In the first case, one is using our eyes' ability to react to electromagnetic waves by triggering a neurophysical process ending with a representation of the color of and geometric relations between external objects in our brain. In brief, we use the electromagnetic waves reflected or emitted by external objects to know something about them (mostly, but not exclusively, geometric features). In such a process, electromagnetic waves are the *carriers* of information.

A completely different thing is to detect features of the electromagnetic field with our eyes. This is possible only partially. Our eyes are able to provide information about some features of the em field. In particular, within some ranges, we can compare the intensity of light or the frequency (color). However, our eyes have not evolved to react to the direction of the fields (polarization), although some birds and other animals are supposed to be able to distinguish different linear polarizations.

One thing should be clear. Representations of vector fields as arrays of arrows with different intensities and orientations are geometrical *representations* of vector fields and do not coincide with the fields. Therefore, in no way an eye could directly see them.